# I can't fetch results from my SQL Procedure

Tags: php

I need help with fetching my data from the database.
I have a procedure that returns a Results Set in the form of three fields: login, password and id. I'd love to get all this data and store it in an array, but It always returns an empty array. I tested the procedure and it works 100%.

PHP CODE:(`$data` is an array of data which im getting from axios post)

```
$login = $data->login;
    $password= $data->password;
    $response = array();
      
    $sql = "CALL xyz_login(:login,:password)";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $statement->bindParam(':login',$login,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $statement->bindParam(':password',$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      

      if($statement->execute()){
          $response[] = $statement->fetchAll();
      }
      else{
      $response[] = "error";
      }
      echo json_encode($response);
      exit;
```

Comment: If `$data` is an array then use `$data['login']` and `$data['password']` instead. Does `var_dump($data)` output the expected values?

Comment: Yes. Problem isn't values of login and Password. login and password returns always expected value.

Comment: Maybe the json encode fails? What does `var_dump($response);` return? What does `echo json_last_error_msg();` return? You don't seem to have done much debugging. And we cant see your stored procedure code or your database data or what input you provided as the login and password, so we've no idea whether it's even reasonable to expect it to return anything to begin with.